# Is it possible to remove a file from the circular dependency chain check?

Tags: angular

Usually, circular dependencies are a sign of bad design in Angular. I have a specific feature that triggers circular dependencies and I am not surprised in this case.

The feature is a `route` pipe which allows me to generate urls dynamically in the templates by using the route name and route parameters, e.g. `<a routerLink="{{ 'my_route_name' | route : {param1: value1, ...} }}">` . This is very handy.

But here is the consequence: the `route` pipe has an indirect dependency on every view component. And as soon as the `route` pipe is used by some components template, the circular dependency is there. I don't think this can be avoided, this is by design and I accept this.

But the warnings are here and they bother me. I would like to avoid disabling the whole circular detection mechanism because it's a good check. So, my question is as follows: is there a way to remove a file from the check? other ideas which could help me solve this issue are welcome.

Thanks